# What does max eval parameter in hyperas optim minimize function returns?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, hyperas

I am trying to tune parameters using Hyperas but I can't interpret few details regarding it.

Q1) What is max_eval parameter in optim.minimize do?

Q2) Does it go through each and every combination of parameters for each max_eval and give me best loss based on best of params?

Q3) What if I give max_eval = 5?

Q4) What does best_run and best_model returns after completing all max_evals?

Q5) Below model function I returned loss as -test_acc what does it has to do with tuning parameter and why do we use negative sign there?

```
def model(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test):    

    dense_units1 = {{choice([64, 126, 256, 512])}}
    activations = {{choice(['relu', 'sigmoid'])}}

    epochs  = 100
    verbose = 0

    model = Sequential([
        # layer 1
        Dense(dense_units1, activations, input_shape=(784,)),
               ....
               ....
               ....

    ])
    # compiling model
    model.compile(optimizers, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    # fitting the model
    result = model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_split=0.2, batch_size=batch_size, 
                        epochs=epochs, verbose=verbose, callbacks=[ES, MC])

    test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=512)

    return {'loss': -test_acc, 'status': STATUS_OK, 'model': model}

best_run, best_model = optim.minimize(model=model, data=dataset, algo=tpe.suggest, 
                                       max_evals=5, 
                                      trials=Trials(), notebook_name='MNIST', 
                                      verbose=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The `max_eval` parameter is simply the maximum number of optimization runs. (e.g. If `max_evals = 5`, Hyperas will choose a different combination of hyperparameters 5 times and run each combination for the amount of epochs you chose)
2. No, It will go through one combination of hyperparamets for each `max_eval`. The best combination of hyperparameters will be after finishing all evaluations you gave in `max_eval` parameter.
3. Answered in Q1.
4. In this case `best_model` and `best_run` will return the same. You should add this to your code:

   ```
   print('Best performing model chosen hyper-parameters:')
   print(best_run)
   ```

   this will print the best hyperparameters from all the runs it made.

Comment: and what does best_model returns?

Comment: It will return the same as `best_run` as stated in answer 4. @MehmedB